# Pagination vs Load More?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

nowadays, I know two methods how to present limited data from database to user.

the first method is using pagination like

> first previous 1 2 3 .. next last

the second method is using

> Load more

like on Facebook or Twitter, but of course this is need AJAX function to load more data.

which one the best to use if we look from system performance or user convenience?

Comment: The sort of data being presented is important in determining the solution.

Comment: They aren't really interchangeable. What data are you presenting?

Comment: I usually prefer the latter way because there I don't have to know how many pages there are. So I'm saving one database call.

Comment: @Blender : it's like article/blog post data actually that consist of text,img,link etc

Comment: give them both performance and convenience. you dont even need to write the code. these classes wrap it for you including growing page counts: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/paging.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which one the best to use if we look from system performance or user convenience?

Assuming that there is no need for a user to jump to page X of results, a "load more" option will (usually) work better for both fronts.

- You'll have slightly lower load on the db server, since you're not making it re-calculate how many pages it has all the time.
- Your users will like the "load more" option, since they won't need to have a full page refresh and can just keep on scrolling.

Of course, neither of those necessarily applies to your exact situation.  If you have a database that has baked-in pagination, or a need of your users to select a particular page, or an existing application that supported paginatino and your users prefer it, then paginagion may be the better choice.

And you forgot the third "infinite scroll" option, btw.

Comment: I think infinite scroll is more or less "load more" that gets clicked for you.

Comment: i think it really comes down to programmer laziness. if you check out http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=66&tab=reputation&filter=quarter and the bottom right, if i was to have to go thru 48000 pages that would be kinda awful. they dont plop in a jump to page # but fortunately you can change the url and go to page 24000 but how many average users would think to do that. so they click the NextPage 24000 times

Comment: Why (as a user) would you ever want to click through to a random page in the stack?  If you're looking for something, the site should have a proper search function.

Comment: it is not random. but that interface does not support it. cuz they were lazy about it. i want to find me, i know based on ranges that i will probably be somewhere in the middle

Comment: @DougM, I think infinite scroll is like "load more button" but automatically clicked/performanced when user scroll down

Comment: why pagination can't be done in AJAX? no need of full page refresh.